# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be nul on laravel and VUE JS

Tags: laravel

i try to save data using vue.js form and laravel,, but i getting error like this

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be nul
```

this is my controller..

```
 public function order(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data['id'] =  $request->input('product');
    $data['product_id'] = $request->input('product_id');
    $data['product_site_id'] = $request->input('product_site_id');
    $data['qty'] = $request->input('qty');
    $data['qty_booking'] = $request->input('qty_booking');
    $data['qty_order'] = $request->input('qty_order');
    $this->productStockRepository->create($data);
    return true;
}
```

and this is my form binding vue.js

```
    <input type="hidden" :name="'product[' + buy_data.id + '][id]'"  :value="buy_data.id">
<input type="hidden" :name="'product[' + buy_data.id + '][product_id]'" :value="buy_data.id">
<input type="hidden" :name="'product[' + buy_data.id + '][product_site_id]'" :value="buy_data.id">
<input type="hidden" :name="'product[' + buy_data.id + '][qty]'" :value="buy_data.qty">
```

plis help where wrong with my code... thannks

Comment: How's your migration/database table?

Comment: the method save into database ProductStocks.. 
and table productSTock be there product_id

Comment: Try `$request->product_id`

Comment: same ,, still error product_id cannot be null

Comment: change in database, store null value in table filed if needed null value.

Comment: product_id is not null... and must fill

Comment: You are assigning buy_data.id to the same value as product_id. What structure is the product_id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `product_id` exist, but you are not accessing it correctly. From your Vue form, we can noticeably see how you name each field;

And to my understanding, if you `dd($request->input())`, you will receive such as following, which is a form of **an array of product**:

```
"product" => [
    [0] => [
        "product_id" => 1,
        "product_site_id" => 1,
        "qty" => 10
    ],
    [1] => [
        "product_id" => 2,
        "product_site_id" => 2,
        "qty" => 5
    ]
]
```

I am sure you have a multiple field of products that you want to create. For this, you need to loop inside `product` array:

```
foreach($request->product as $product) {
    $this->productStockRepository->create($product);
}
```

**Note**: If your field name is equal to your column name, you don't need to assign manually. For example, you can do as above, instead of following:

```
$data['id'] =  $request->input('product');
$data['product_id'] = $request->input('product_id');
$data['product_site_id'] = $request->input('product_site_id');
// ...
```

And you could also call `$request->product` instead of `$request->input('product')`

Also, I recommend to rename `products` with plural `products` which made it more readable especially when you perform a loop. Consider following beautiful and readable syntax.

```
foreach($request->products as $product) {
    $this->productStockRepository->create($product);
}
```

Notice that a single `product` is from a list of `products`? It just made sense, and help other programmer to read better your code.

#### Prerequisite

Like mentioned by others, be sure `product_id` is mentioned inside `$fillable`.

Answer (score 0):

Add product_id to the fillable array of the model.

```
class X extends Model
{    
    protected $fillable = [
        'x',
        'y',
        ...,
        'product_id'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make product_id column in your database table **nullable**

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `dd(request()->all());` I think you'll see that your date is not formed correctly, as you're setting the `:name` attribute equal to the value of the property.
Try inspecting the compiled HTML to view the name of the input, it may help as well.